# Jquery click event in new window

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, triggers, click

Hello i wonder if i can open a link and trigger a click like this:

nothing happens at the moment.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.open("url");
    $("object").delay(2500).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: What is object? Is it an id of a link? And what is the window.open for? I'm afraid I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: object is the class what i looking for (example ".button"). I try to open a link an click automaticly an button.

Comment: Is the `.button` in the current window, or the new one?

Comment: If it's a class, then that should be $(".object") etc. Notice the period. That's what tells jQuery it's a class!

Comment: in the new one thats the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't see that it was cross-domain, it's almost impossible to invoke javascript into another window.

If you try an iframe with the following code:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    var iframe = this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument;

    $(iframe).find('h1').text('Changed title');
}).attr('src', 'http://example.com');
```

An error will appear into the console:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

You can try it yourself [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qh5k19a/).

Chrome blocks adding custom javascript, because it would be a hudge security leak. For example: you load Facebook into an iframe and you add a event listener on the 'login'-button that you send the username and password to your servers. The user would think he is safely logged in, but in the background the password was send to the other server.

I think you might do it another way. Like a POST request. But I don't know what the situation is.

Comment: Was this your answer? If so you could mark it as answer. ;)

Comment: Ohh Yeah sorry i forgot :) thanks for the help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

1 way of doing this is using `hash`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.open("url#click");
});
```

on the other page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#click'){
        $(".button").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not 100% what i am looking for. The Other page is an external site, so i can not implement my own jquery :)

Comment: I am unaware of a way you can achieve this sorry.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're in the DOM of the current page and not the poup.

If you do the following:

```
var popup = window.open('/');

popup.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(popup.document.body).find("object").click();
    }, 2500);
}, false);
```

It will access the DOM of the popup.

See this fiddle for an example to delete the logo http://jsfiddle.net/anrk8n83/1/ on the Fiddle editor.

**NOTE** This will not work cross-domain.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. Now i have the problem that the other site use data-postid can i use this like that: `$(popup.document.body).find("a[data-postid='1361']").delay(3500).trigger("click");` and then it should automaticly click this "button"?

Comment: you advised on my answer that it was on an external site and on the note on this answer it says it wont work for cross domain.

Comment: @Caststupider Yes, it should work. But notice that .delay() only will delay animated functions (slideUp, animate etc), so the trigger will not be delayed. setTimeout will work fine. I'll change the preview.